# FFmpeg: overlay srt on image in video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and my first post here.
what i have and what i want to do is below:

- I have video, transparent image and .srt file
- Video with dimension width:1280 Height:720.
- Transparent image with dimension width:1024 Height:122.
- .srt file with font sytle stored in html tags.

My goal is to overlay the image with srt text exactly in center and the overlayed image to be exactly in center video.

I started by subtracting the dimension of video with transparent image to position it exactly at center.

```
ImageX = (video.width - image.width)/2
ImageY = (video.Height - Image.height) * 0.9 (to bottom of video).
```

After researching i got this code:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Projects\Video Phase 3\Horse\horse.mp4" -i "C:\Projects\Video Phase 3\Horse\Transparent.png" -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=128:538:enable='between(t,0,1)', subtitles=C\\:\\\\Projects\\\\Video Phase 3\\\\Horse\\\\ImportedTrack1_0.srt[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a "C:\Projects\Video Phase 3\Horse\newout.mp4"
```

i am able to put the transparent image exactly at center,bottom. But i am not able to position the srt text in image.
even if i put the image in Top center, i need to put the text in center of image. Please help me guys

[Captured image from out video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utm1G.png)

Comment: thanks I will try to force_style, let me see what i get.for the second comment - my project requirement is that users should be allowed to load image at runtime and then text should be overlayed on image and then video . i cannot use drawbox for this.

Comment: i tried the force_style alignment, but it places the srt on top of the video. It would be a manual task to set the alignment everytime. How can i dynamically set the subtitles to place in center middle of the transparent image.

Comment: Try `Alignment=10`.

Comment: ok, but how can it be dynamic, say if user changes the font size at runtime

Comment: It should still be centered no matter the font size.

Comment: thanks it works, but may i know how the alignment works. Say if i change my image position at runtime (ex: i put image in some custom position of video), how would i know the alignment of font position that needs to exactly in middle center of image

Comment: I see what you want now. I read the question and saw the image but for some reason assumed you wanted background image and subtitles in middle center. You can use ASS subtitles with the [`\pos` and `\an` tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/) to position the subtitles. Alternatively, use drawtext filter with `x` and `y` options.